# counting nodes and elements in a DOM tree with a recursive JS function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to count all nodes and Elements (in two different variables) of a DOM tree using a recursive vanilla JavaScript function

i tried something like this

```
    let nodeSum = 0;

function recursiveCount(node) {
  if (node.childNodes) {
    let childnodes = node.childNodes;
    nodeSum += childnodes.length;
    let nextchild = node.firstElementChild;
    let nextsibling = node.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextsibling) {
      return recursiveCount(nextsibling);
    }
    return recursiveCount(nextchild);
  }
  return;
}
recursiveCount(document);
```

this is the error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null
why is this happening?

Comment: great. where is your try?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried (provide us with code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to count nodes using simple mutual recursion. This counts all nodes, including text nodes -

```js
const count = ({ childNodes = [] }) =>
  1 + countChildren([...childNodes])
    
const countChildren = (nodes = []) =>
  nodes.reduce((r, n) => r + count(n), 0)

const e =
  document.querySelector('article')

console.log(count(e))
// 23
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum...</h1>
  <p>foo bar qux</p>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
  <p>foo bar qux</p>
</article>
```

As you can see, the logic for traversing a node is entangled with the counting logic. By separating the traversal into its own function, we can easily perform various computations without duplicating traversal logic.

Below `count` depends on `traverse`, keeping its unique focus on the specific (and possibly complex) counting logic -

```js
const traverse = function* (node = {})
{ yield node                           // include this node
  for (const child of node.childNodes) // and for each of this node's children
    yield* traverse(child)             // traverse each child
}

const count = (node = {}) =>
  Array                               // create array
    .from(traverse(node))             // of all nodes
    .reduce                           // then reduce
      ( ([ nodes, elems ], { nodeType }) => // each node
          nodeType === 1                    // if node is Element type,
            ? [ nodes + 1, elems + 1 ]      // count as node and elem
            : [ nodes + 1, elems ]          // otherwise just count as node
      , [ 0, 0 ]                      // using these initial counts
      )

const e =
  document.querySelector('article')

const [ nodes, elems ] =
  count(e)

console.log(`nodes: ${nodes}, elems: ${elems}`)
// nodes: 23, elems: 8
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum...</h1>
  <p>foo bar qux</p>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
  <p>foo bar qux</p>
</article>
```

If the goal is only to count `Element` nodes, we can simplify the `reduce` -

```js
const traverse = function* (node = {})
{ yield node                           // include this node
  for (const child of node.childNodes) // and for each of this node's children
    yield* traverse(child)             // traverse each child
}

const count = (node = {}) =>
  Array                      // create array
    .from(traverse(node))    // of all nodes
    .reduce                  // then reduce
      ( (r, { nodeType }) => // each node
          nodeType === 1     // if node is Element type,
            ? r + 1          // increase count by one
            : r              // otherwise keep count the same
      , 0                    // using this initial count
      )

const e =
  document.querySelector('article')

const elems =
  count(e)

console.log(`elems: ${elems}`)
// elems: 8
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum...</h1>
  <p>foo bar qux</p>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
  <p>foo bar qux</p>
</article>
```

Which could be probably be improved with the use of `filter` -

```
const add = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a + b

const count = (node = {}) =>
  Array                                       // create array
    .from(traverse(node))                     // of all nodes
    .filter(({ nodeType }) => nodeType === 1) // keeping only Element nodes
    .reduce(add, 0)                           // then sum
```

Answer (score 0):

It might error when a `node` has some `childNodes` but none of the children is an `element`. In this case `nextchild = node.firstElementChild` will be `null` and you pass it here `recursiveCount(nextchild)` without any checks causing a throw on this line: `if (node.childNodes) {`.